# Don't get the touch event when using overlapping views

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I have an iPhone app with this screen:

[image: Screenshot 1]

When the user taps a textfield, an autocomplete box pops up. This is a UITableView, that gets put on top of everything, while the underlying UI components are hidden. I want the rows in this table to be selectable. However, only the top ~10 pixels respond to the touch event, as illustrated below.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Any ideas what might be causing this?

**Update:**

I suspect that what might be going on is that the views lying below the autocomplete table might be capturing the events. See how the area that doesn't respond to touch starts exactly where the underlying toggle control starts. However, event handlers on the underlying toggle aren't called, so I'm not positive this is what's going on.

**Update 2:**

Removing the toggle button doesn't change the behavior, so the problem is not that the toggle is capturing the events.

Comment: did you make your custom UITableViewCell ? check it,
also, check your table's numberOfRows.

Comment: where you are added tableview?

Comment: @relower: There's no custom UITableViewCell. The number of rows in the TableViewSource (if that's what you meant) uses some very simple code, and can't really have a bug in it as far as I can see.

Comment: @NeverBe, the table view is added as a sibling to all the other views. That is, everything is put in the root UIView, and I use the `hidden` property to hide/display it.

Comment: You should be sure that numberofrows is not zero. And look at your Cell height, you might be forget to set it.
As advice, set your cell's backgroundColor black or something, and see these all showing on the screen to be sure cells are created.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to give you an answer (and not just educated guesses).

Comment: @relower, The number of rows is not zero, I have verified this with a debugger. Setting a background color shows that the cells are as they should be.

Comment: do you have something transparent above tableview?

Comment: @poupou: What code would you like to see? The view hierarchy is generated entirely through the Interface Builder. I'll update the question with some thoughts on what might be going on. (Thanks for the help BTW!)

Comment: @NeverBe: No, there's nothing transparent there, but I suspect something similar might be going on, i.e. maybe the views below the autocomplete table are the ones that receive the touch event (even though they're hidden).

Comment: i see two buttons below textfield. seems they are a problem. Try remove them for test

Comment: Good point @NeverBe. But alas, I removed the toggle button, and nothing changed.

Comment: Sure, hang on while I find a way to share it.

Comment: Here is the xib: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19547501/RoutePlanningViewController.xib

Comment: background for table is overlapping table view, just swap them

Comment: Thank you @NeverBe, that was it! I set z-positions in code, and things looked right visually, but removing the background (which I didn't really need) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background for table is overlapping table view, just swap them